# Getting 501 Unsupported Method ('Post') error when attempting to login to admin

Tags: admin, authentication

## Server Spec:

- Wordpress 3.0.1
- PHP Version 5.3.8-1+b1
- MYSQL 5.1
- Apache/2.3.16
- Linux

## The Problem

Simple really. A website that I helped to build and install a while back has just been transferred to a new host. The front end of the website isn't presenting any issues, but when I try to login to the admin area, I get a 501 'Unsupported Method ('POST') error.

I'm a bit lost, my guess would be it's a server config issue, but are there any specific wordpress issues that might be at fault?

Comment: Since you just moved to a new host, and are getting a server error back ... this is *definitely* a server configuration issue.  Migrating to Stack Overflow ...